# Disable materialize.css modal footer button

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

I want to disable one of the modal footer button of materialize.css and I used `disabled="disabled"` but it doesn't work. Here's my example on [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pkj18ga2/).

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Agree</a>
      <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">I want to disable this</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask].

Comment: I'm sorry, is there anything wrong on the way how I ask the question?

Comment: use disabled class to your a link

Comment: class="disabled" is still clickable, it is just used for styling. I used disabled="disabled" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Agree</a>
      <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat " disabled="true" >I want to disable this</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What a silly mistake. I used disabled="disabled" and it doesn't work but I never tried disabled="true". This code works now, thanks!

Comment: For everyone it happens, I would appreciate if you could vote my answer and press worked.

Comment: I already did, that's why you have 16 rep now. Unfortunately, my vote won't be posted visually here because I have below 15 rep but still, it is recorded on your profile.